# Text is not within the box range

Tags: html

I have this code that overlaps within the box range and I am wondering how can I line break when it overlaps within the box range.

Html:

```
            <%
                for(Notification n: notifications) {
            %>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <span class="message">
                        <%=n.getMessage()%>
                    </span>
                    <span class="subject">
                        <span class="time">
                            <%=n.getTime()%>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <%}%>
```

Image:

[image]

Comment: Where is the CSS?..... I guess you need to specify the width of the box and set overflow to hidden

Comment: @Nakib Is there a way to line break instead of hidden?

Comment: ya just set specific width and it will automatically do for you.

Comment: @Nakib I tried it but it is still not working

Comment: try using word-wrap: break-word;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the link isn't loading,

but you can use CSS

```
<div>
    <h4>aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa<h4>
</div>

div {width: 100px;border: 1px solid red;word-wrap: break-word}
```

or JS

```
string = 'aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa'

string = string.replace(/(.{1,20})/g, '$1<br/>')

document.write(string);
```

CSS would be the better option

https://jsfiddle.net/ednmstpz/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

white-space:nowrap;overflow:hidden;

To the li tag

Comment: Is there something a line break instead of hidden?

Comment: For some reason the link is not loading properly